# cannot load such file -- refinery (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mailchimp, refinerycms

I'm dealing with this error below. It started form gem file when I initialized Mailchimp - *gem 'refinerycms-mailchimp', :branch => 'refinery-2.0'*

> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- refinery (LoadError)  from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`
>   block in require'    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in
>   `load_dependency'     from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`
>   require'     from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/refinerycms-mailchimp-0.0.2/lib/refinerycms-mailchimp.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`
>   require'     from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in
>   `block (2 levels) in require'     from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in`
>   each'    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in
>   `block in require'    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in`
>   each'    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in
>   `require'     from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in`
>   require'     from
>   /home/elvijs/workspace/dzma2/config/application.rb:13:in `<top
>   (required)>'  from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in`
>   require'     from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in
>   `block in <top (required)>'   from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in`
>   tap'     from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from script/rails:6:in`require'    from
>   script/rails:6:in `'

Comment: Could you post the content of your Gemfile?

Comment: Point the branch to master . Does pointing to other versions cause the same error ?